Position: fixed is behaving like postion: absolute in react + tailwind
I'm using React with Tailwind
I'm trying to center the modal in the screen in which the height of the body is more than that of viewport and I need the modal to be fixed at the center of the screen.
Here's a link to the page
https://yla-frontend.vercel.app/account/profile
Click on edit name button after scrolling a bit, you get a dialog box, it always starts relatively from the top of the container even though the position is fixed.
Screenshot
Can someone please help
I've created a parent container which is fixed, with top and left 0 and width and height as 100vw and 100vh, and then inside this container I've tried to centre the modal inside this div.
The problem is that the parent container acts like it is positioned as absolute and moves to the top of the entire content and not on fixed on the screen. Thus scrolling with the rest of the content

You can set the parent element (element with black background) to have a fixed position and occupy the entire height of the viewport.
.parent {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 2000;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   overflow: none;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}


I've done exactly this, it is still not working

You are probably just putting your modal at top:0 and left:0 I would fix that by using the scrollY property of window.
<Modal className=`absolute top-[-${window.ScrollY}] ...restOfClasses` />

Notice how I put the value as a negative so it goes downwards instead of upwards.

No this is not it, I've used a parent container with 100vh height and 100vw width. This container I've put as top:0 and left:0. Please checkout the url and see the styling

Your class does exactly what I said. fixed top-0 left-0 will always put your modal at the top of it's parent container (The user's details) that top being the top of your app.
Check my example. Notice how wherever you are the modal shows at the position you. You can just update my plain css to taillwind clases and also handle the background scrolling when the modal is open.
PS. I was wrong about putting the value as a negative. But it's fixed in the playground

I think you didn't get the problem I'm facing. You see, I want to have parent container's position fixed, and even though I have done that, it's showing the absolute like behaviour. In your playground if I am adding position:fixed to your modal, it is behaving the way I want you to but not on my app, I want to find out the reason why?
